# MiniMagick error: undefined method 'size' for nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-processing, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, minimagick

`undefined method 'size' for nil:NilClass` occurs at `MiniMagick::Utilities.which('mogrify').size` in `def choose_processor`  `mini_magick (3.7.0) lib/mini_magick.rb`.

It seems like mini_magick gem doesn't find my ImageMagick.

I am using Windows 7, mini_magick 3.7.0, Rails 4.0.2, Ruby 2.0.0p353, ImageMagick 6.8.8-1

code:

```
version :normal do
   process resize_to_limit: [1028,850]
end
```

ImageMagick is installed:

```
C:\Users>convert -version
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.8-1 Q16 x64 2013-12-25 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2014 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: DPC Modules OpenMP
Delegates: bzlib cairo freetype jbig jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr pangocairo png ps rsv
g tiff webp xml zlib
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that ImageMagick, specifically the command `mogrify`, is on your PATH environment variable at the point where MiniMagick is first called.  Depending on how you start your application, it is easy to end up with a different path than what you have within your command prompt.

To debug the issue, inspect the value of `ENV['PATH']` just before the place where the error is occurring.  You will probably see that ImageMagick's folder is missing from your path.

You will then want to add a line like the following to `application.rb`, `environments/production.rb`, or some other appropriate place:

```rb
ENV['PATH'] += File::PATH_SEPARATOR + 'C:\path\to\imagemagick'
```

This will guarantee that your path contains the correct location of ImageMagick.

Comment: Interesting answer.  How would you go about this debugging? Considering my development environment already has a line:  
  ENV['PATH'] = "/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.4/bin:#{ENV['PATH']}"
to deal with the fact that postgreSQL needs to be properly picked up (Apple pre-installs in a different place)

Comment: This question was from a Windows user, while it appears that you are on Mac OS.  I used File::PATH_SEPARATOR to support either OS; you can safely do it that way or just extend the line you already added to include the path to Imagemagick on your development machine.